# Had major overheat issue but engine was rebuilt 3 months ago

Tags: engine, oil-leak, overheating

I had my engine completely rebuilt three months ago (new gaskets, timing belt, water pump, etc.) and yesterday the engine completely overheated (temperature was at the mid-line, then 10 minutes later it was maxed out)

I could smell something burning and when I saw the temperature gauge I pulled over immediately and saw that the car was leaking oil from the bottom (oil pan) and I couldn't tell if there was any coolant left in the system (may have boiled away during the overheating)

I had it towed back to the shop that did the engine rebuild and I'm waiting to hear what they say about who's responsible for this but what questions should I ask them and what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Which make, model, engine and year?

Comment: Daewoo Lanos, 1.5L SOHC, 2000

Answer (score 2):

From your description, they did something wrong. It sounds as though there is a leaking gasket or the pan itself is leaking oil, which when low enough (oil), would cause an overheating issue. If the engine ran out of oil, this could cause your overheating issue, though you would have seen an oil light flash on first. I'm thinking the leaking you saw was not oil, but probably coolant. Loss of coolant (*obviously*) would have caused an overheat issue as well. Still, it would seem (from your limited description) this would fall back on the shop.